# How to use array variable in my sql statement in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

total nube in PL/PGSQL. I would like to define an array of strings and then used that in my SELECT... WHERE In statement but can't seem to get it to work, help appreciated.

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    testArray varchar[] := array['john','lisa'];    
    ids integer[];
BEGIN
    ids = array(select id from tableA where name in (testArray));
    -- this works
    ids = array(select id from tableA where name in ('john','lisa'));
END $$;
```

Comment: Use =any() like this: where name =any (testArray))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any near of testarray.

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    testArray varchar[] := array['john','lisa'];    
    ids integer[];
BEGIN
    ids = array(select id from tableA where name = any(testArray));
    -- this works
    ids = array(select id from tableA where name in ('john','lisa'));
END $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_agg` to group the ids and store them in the variable using `into`, and with the operator `any` you can use the array of names in the where clause, e.g:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    testArray varchar[] := array['john','lisa'];    
    ids integer[];
BEGIN
    SELECT array_agg(id) INTO ids
    FROM tableA 
    WHERE name = ANY(testArray);
END $$;
```